# Flutter CRON / TIMER / STATE doesn't work on Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, cron, setstate

I have some trouble making my app work on Android and NOX emulator whilst not debugging. I've tried with both CRON (https://pub.dev/packages/cron) and dart:async (TIMER) to make things run each second or minute.

Running my app on both iOS and Android emulator locally on my Macbook it runs fine, the snackbar shows with the time stamp each second, the content displays without issues based on my if statements etc.

Running the app on another PC using NOX for example or installing the APK on live Android phone, nothing happens, the snackbar doesn't show, content stays hidden, it's like either the cron/timer is not running or state is not being updated, any ideas why?

Example using CRON

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();

    //Get current time every second from the api to get server time
    cron.schedule(Schedule.parse('*/1 * * * * *'), () async {
      var url =
          Uri.https('my_api_site.com', '/api/date', {'q': '{http}'});
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
      
      //Sets state to hide/show content based on time of the day.
      setState(() {
        time = int.parse(jsonResponse['hour'] + jsonResponse['minute']);
      });

      //Display a snackbar with current timestamp for testing purposes
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
        SnackBar(content: Text('Timestamp: $time')),
      );
    });
    
  }
```

And example using timer

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => _getTime());
}

//Get current time every second from the api to get server time
void _getTime() async {
    var url = Uri.https('my_api_site.com', '/api/date', {'q': '{http}'});
    var response = await http.get(url);
    var jsonResponse = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);

    //Sets state to handle visible content based on time
    setState(() {
      time = int.parse(jsonResponse['hour'] + jsonResponse['minute']);
    });

    //Display a snackbar with current timestamp for testing purposes
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
      SnackBar(content: Text('Timestamp: $time')),
    );
  }
```

**Update:**
I've done some more testing and i keep getting these "warnings" when building the apk. Ive tried updating, all pubs and dart/null-safety and warnings still persists.

```
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01
Warning: Mapping new ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/02 to old ns http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

Other overflow questions states it's related to versions of sdk missmatch but shouldn't cause issues and i've tried their fixes but doesn't seem to work with the latest version of flutter/dart/etc.

**Another update:** It seems like using the cron task and snackbar works without issue on android, the problem seem to be with the http request OR setState, will continue to look into this matter.